# Why am I getting commas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex

I want to get rid of the commas that I tried so hard and couldn't do. I looked at all the sources on internet everybody said .replace(some regex) -> I tried that one and it didn't work, node.js and jquery's error is that .replace() is not a function.

I am parsing this data from the JSON file and client-side is jquery with ajax.

Output:

I am thinking my regex function is wrong, I need a function which can scan all my JSON file and find the URLs A.K.A that starts with ftp/http/https/www etc,

Thanks!

Comment: show us your regex function and the data your trying to parse, Also is it only commas you need to get rid of ?

Comment: Can you show what data you wanna parse? It's in string right? Or you are loading whole json file as a string and matching?

Comment: Yeah it is only commas that I need to get rid of because I need to parse the URLs from the JSON data I will use them.

Comment: I am uploading the data one second please I just uploaded my code. Yes whole json file as a string but there are some integer values in it

Comment: @DaveAmit I uploaded a snippet of JSON, I need to find both of the URLs I typed and I also uploaded my parsing code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @thisOneGuy I uploaded a snippet of JSON, I need to find both of the URLs I typed and I also uploaded my parsing code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a function to extract urls from a given JSON object.

> NOTE: This function will work on node.js as well !! :)

```
function extractUrls(data) {
      var s = JSON.stringify(data);
      var regx = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

      return s.match(regx);
    }
```

And following is the data that you wanna scan through (its structure does not matter)

```
var data = [{
  "id": 4797492459,
  "text": "She was lucky that she could use href=\"http://www.google.com\" right?",
  "user": {
    "url": "http://whatever.com"
  }
}, {
  "id": 4797490987,
  "text": "She was unlucky that she could not use href=\"http://www.google.in\" right?",
  "user": {
    "url": "http://another-whatever.com"
  }
}];
```

Then following line of code

```
var urlArray = extractUrls(data);

console.log(urlArray);
```

Will produce an array

```
 [
    "http://www.google.com", 
    "http://whatever.com", 
    "http://www.google.in", 
    "http://another-whatever.com" 
 ]
```

> NOTE: everything till here will work in node.js as well.
>
> JQuery example.
>   Following is an fiddler example

https://jsfiddle.net/wdkdwk2g/1/

> Full fiddler code
>   js

```
var data = [{
  "id": 4797492459,
  "text": "She was lucky that she could use href=\"http://www.google.com\" right?",
  "user": {
    "url": "http://whatever.com"
  }
}, {
  "id": 4797490987,
  "text": "She was unlucky that she could not use href=\"http://www.google.in\" right?",
  "user": {
    "url": "http://another-whatever.com"
  }
}];

function extractUrls(data) {
  var s = JSON.stringify(data);
  var regx = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

  return s.match(regx);
}

var urlArray = extractUrls(data);

console.log(urlArray);

urlArray.forEach(function(url) {
  $('ul').append('<li>' + url + '</li>');
});
```

> HTML

```
<ul></ul>
```

> Output

[image]

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Let me know if you need anything else!

:)

Comment: The thing is that data is long and anywhere in the data it can be an URL and I need a list of them, I need my code to scan them and find them, I need all of them. So, I need an iterative code which can find all of them and getting rid of the commas. My code that I share find all of them, I can't just get rid of the commas.

Comment: Oh... Ok. Now I got it. I'm on my way home. I'll get back with the solution in about half an hour!

Comment: Ok so suppose this is your data `[ {
  "id":4797492459,
  "text": "She was lucky that she could use href=\"http://www.google.com\" right?",
  "user":{ "url": "http://whatever.com"}
},{
  "id":4797490987,
  "text": "She was unlucky that she could not use href=\"http://www.google.in\" right?",
  "user":{ "url": "http://another-whatever.com" }
}]` and you want following output `['http://www.google.com','http://whatever.com','http://www.google.in','http://another-whatever.com']` .... is this right?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: forgot to mention I need node.js code to parse the data :)

Comment: `extractUrls` will work on node as well! its pure js. just use it like `var urls = extractUrls(_your_json_object_which_you_wanna_scan);` and there you have all your urls in an array!!

Comment: perfectly works thank you so much I didn't even need to change my jquery but is it possible to print links line by line?

Comment: Yes you can, try the fiddler that I have attached. Its an array right? just do a `forEach` and append to `ul` or generate just join array like this `urlArray.join('<br/>')` and append to a `span` tag. i.e.. `<span id='linksWillGoHere'></span>` then doing this `$('#linksWillGoHere').html(urlArray.join('<br/>'));` will do the trick !! Have fun and be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = ".edu,http,,our.risd.edu,,,, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,";

var str2 = str1.replace(/,/g, '');

console.log(str2);
```

note 'g' flag in the end of regex pattern